# Excel Data Validation marked with value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of items in column A and for some of the items, column B has value "Y". How do I only include the items of column A marked with "Y" in a data validation list?

I have tried this in the data validation formula but doesn't seem to work:

```
INDEX('Mysheet'!$A$8:$A$240,SUMPRODUCT(--('Mysheet'!$B$8:$B$240="Y")))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2016+ with the `FILTER` function, you can

- Enter this formula someplace on the worksheet:  `=INDEX(FILTER(A1:B10,B1:B10="y"),0,1)`
- Create a dynamic name definition.  For example:

  myList refers to:  `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$1,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$D:$D)-1)`
- You can then use a Validation formula for the List:

```
     =myList
```

If you don't have the `FILTER` function, you can use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($B$1:$B$10="y")*ROW($B$1:$B$10),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

and fill down until you get blanks, or at least as far as you might have `y`'s in column B.

Then for the formula name (which has to be a bit different because of the blanks in the list):

```
refers to:  =OFFSET(Sheet1!$F$1,1,0,SUM(--(LEN(Sheet1!$F:$F)>0))-1)
```